# Can I perform queries in Django where both the LHS and RHS are a function?

Tags: django, django-orm

I'd like to perform queries in Django where both the left-hand-side and right-hand-side are a function. I'm trying to implement some complex query handling (writing a WFS server), where situations like these could occur:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE LCASE('LiteralValue') = LOWER(field2)`

Is this possible using the `QuerySet.filter(..)` or `Q(..)` objects API?
It always expects the expression to start with a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you cn annotate the model objects by one of the sides, and then filter with the other side:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

QuerySet.objets.annotate(
    field1_lower=Lower('field1')
).filter(
    field1_lower=Lower('field2')
)
```

For case-invariant matching, you should however use the [**`__iexact`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact):

```
from django.db.models import F

QuerySet.objets.filter(
    field1__iexact=F('field2')
)
```

Note that case-insensitive matching is *not* the same as calling `Lower` on the two operands, and then check if the two match. Indeed, the collation defines specific rules to handle special characters. For example in German the *ß* has no lowercase variant. There are special rules how to compare these.

Comment: Hmm the annotations give a good idea! The solution needs to be very generic, hence the question.

Comment: Django 3.2 has introduced [`alias()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.alias) for QuerySets; being the same as `annotate()` but for situations where you don't want to `SELECT` the result of the expression, improving performance where you _only_ want to filter on the expression.